# PIL Module not being seen

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm using VSCode on a Mac. Python 3.9 In VSCode, Python 3.9.6 64-bit ('venv':venv)

I have successfully created a virtual environment and I'm trying to use the Image Library (PIL)

- I've gotten Pillow installed in the venv and it shows up with Pip List
- There is no error showing up (red squiggle) in the editor window when I use from PIL import Image
- When I run the program, I get ImportError: No module named PIL

**This is the code:**

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('church in munich.jpg')
image2 = Image.open('cool car in italy.jpg')

image.show()

plt.imshow(image)
plt.imshow(image2)
```

**The output results:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/NewMacStorage/VSCode Work/PythonWork/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I've included what VSCode looks like:

[image]

Anybody know what the problem could be?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running your code? Are you using the virtual env's interpreter?

Comment: @brian I am running it with the virtual env's interpreter, yes. It shows current being the /venv/bin/python

Comment: Could there be a problem with pillow module version and python version?

Comment: @thirdsandfourths , I *think* and being a newbie, that's a stretch, I've three variables I'm dealing with: evenv vs just a VScode workspace or the combination of Pillow and Python3.  Step one, for me at least, is to ask here.  I'm not clear on Workspace vs. venv so it is entirely possible/likely, I've got a configuration mucked up.

Comment: did you "source" the `venv` before running the code?

Comment: @sagar1025 , sorry I'm not following.  Could you explain further.

Comment: before running the code, did you run this command `source venv/bin/activate`? if not, try running that first, then execute the script. Or did you at any point run `source venv/bin/activate`?

Comment: @sagar1025, sorry I got confused but, yes, I did indeed.  The steps used were to get the venv set up, ensure I was in it via the terminal command, mkdir test, and then code ., launching VSCode, where I am now.  I did in the VSC terminal verify I was in the right venv, properly installed the packages (pillow, etc.).

Comment: All.  I got this error resolved and the code shown above runs. @sagar1025, I went back and re-did the entire Virtual Env steps, made a fresh one and I believe what did the trick in VSC was to ensure that the interpreter was  pointed to ~/rickland/... which was the virtual env that I created.  This problem is all over stackoverflow.  Do I answer the question myself and lay out what I did so others can see the solution?
Brian, I think you were essentially telling me this, thanks, hat tip.

Comment: @RickSegal yes you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some pointers from people here (thank you), this problem lies in a combination of PATH confusion (i.e. where things are being read from), Virtual Environments being properly set up and active, and pointing VSCode to the right interpreter.

To solve this on my Mac:

- Exit from VScode.  Likely not required but I wanted to eliminate all variables of what was running, etc.
- Go to a terminal window outside of VSC
- Set up your virtual environment
- Activate it
- From within that space "code ." will launch VSCode
- When you create a .py file, make sure you are using the proper interpreter on that code which you can see/set/change by going to the command pallet and using the command Python: Select interpreter that is associated with your virtual environment.  I named my environment "codeland" so that when I looked at the list of interpreter selections, it was obvious to me.  You can use the venv default as well.
- I opened the terminal window inside VScode and, sure enough, I was in the virtual environment I had set up.

From there, installing and using modules like pillow (PIL) inside my code worked fine.